# Add Timestamp to extracted thumbnail's name from a video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I have a requirement of generating thumbnails(camera change, slide change, scene change) from a videofile with it's timestamp(pos) included in the generated output thumbnails.

I used the following command to generate thumbnails:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync 0 -an keyframe-%06d.png
```

This command works absolutely fine for generating thumbnails (assume 15 thumbnails are generated) with names in sequence like: keyframe-000001.png, keyframe-000002.png, .... , keyframe-000015.png.

But, according to my requirement, I need the output thumbnail file names something like as follows:

> keyframe-001426.png, keyframe-002769.png, .... , keyframe-014571.png where
>
> 001426 is the position of thumbnail keyframe-000001.png
>
> 002769 is the position of thumbnail keyframe-000002.png
>
> 014571 is the position of thumbnail keyframe-000015.png

Is there a way to achieve this in a single command.? Please help me out achieving this.

Comment: [This is a non-single command solution using `ffprobe`](http://superuser.com/questions/885452/extracting-the-index-of-key-frames-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg). The idea is to use `ffprobe` to extract the index of the key frames first and then rename the files accordingly.